# background: transparent; vs background: 0 0; differences and threats

Tags: css, background, less

I've noticed that `background: transparent` is changed into `background: 0 0;` using `less`. I'm using `grunt-contrib-less` in `1.4.1` version that uses `"less": "~2.7.1"` to transform less to css. What these `0 0` in background are responsible for? Are there any treats resulting from using `background: 0 0` instead of `background: transparent`? I tried to google this but i couldn't find anything that will explain me that

Comment: `background: 0 0;` is nothing but you can give `background-size:0;` or `background-position:0` and for background image `background-image:none;`

Comment: Less itself *never* does this kind of changes. What you see is the result of some other tool in your CSS build chain (most likely [a minifier](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/167)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Practically you will not get any treats by using the property `background: 0 0;` rather `background: transparent`
 what exactly this `background: 0 0` is short hand notation of

```
background-image: initial;
background-position-x: 0;
background-position-y: 0;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
```

Where every background property is set to initial and `background position` is set to `0 0` and answer for your another question why Less is changing `background:transparent` to `background: 0 0` is IE7 or below doesnt support `transparent` property so Less is changing it into another shorthand notation which gives the same output

Comment: Thanks for answer and telling me why less changes it this way

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background): (Bold mine)

> The background CSS shorthand property assigns explicit given values
>   **and sets missing properties to their initial values**.

Both versions: `background: transparent` and `background: 0 0;` reset all background properties to their initial values except that each one explicitly sets their own particular background property.

`background: transparent` - sets `background-color` with `transparent`

`background: 0 0;` sets `background-position` with `0 0`

There shouldn't be a problem interchanging them (so no 'threats')

Answer (score 1):

`background: 0 0` sets the background position to `background-position: 0 0` and not to transparent.

`background-color` initial value is transparent.

`background: none` sets the `background-image: none`

Comment: this is just plain wrong. In all possible ways. background: 0 0 doesn´t set the position to 0. simple tested if you set a background image to anything and then use background-position: 0 0 and background: 0 0. background-position will probably change how the background is displayed, instead will background: 0 0 remove the image

Comment: made my answer more accurate (pressed anter too fast) - edit: I´d like to add: background: 0 0 sets position to 0 0 but thats not all it does

Comment: @MarcelSchmid it removes the image because you are overwriting you `background` property. A valid css would be `background: url('your-url') 0 0;`

Comment: yes this would work. but in your answer you say "background 0 0" is the same as "background-position: 0 0" which is completly wrong, cause as you said or better the right answer shows it does alot more then background-position: 0 0